# How can I dynamically mount an external USB hard drive in RancherOS?

Tags: docker, rancher

Like the title states, I have RancherOS installed on a baremetal host and want
to dynamically handle addition/removal of an external USB hard drive. It should be accessible as a bind mount for other containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```yaml
# udev_config.yml
write_files:
- path: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-media-Storage-usb-drive.rules
  container: udev
  permissions: "0644"
  owner: root
  content: |
    ATTRS{ID_FS_UUID}!="161E-5755", GOTO="media_Storage_usb_drive_exit"
    ACTION=="add", \
      RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/udev-mount.sh -o nodev,noexec,nosuid,uid=1100,gid=5000,umask=007 $root/$name /media/Storage"
    ACTION=="remove", \
      RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/udev-umount.sh /media/Storage"
    LABEL="media_Storage_usb_drive_exit"
- path: /usr/bin/udev-mount.sh
  container: udev
  permissions: "0755"
  owner: root
  content: |
    #!/bin/sh
    set -e
    eval path=\${$#}
    system-docker exec console /usr/bin/mkdir -p "$path"
    system-docker exec console /usr/bin/mount "$@"
- path: /usr/bin/udev-umount.sh
  container: udev
  permissions: "0755"
  owner: root
  content: |
    #!/bin/sh
    system-docker exec console /usr/bin/umount "$@"
```

Then execute

```sh
sudo ros config merge -i udev_config.yml && sudo ros service restart udev
```

You can unplug and plug in your device or if you know your `DEVNAME` (see below) e.g. `/dev/sdb1`, execute

```sh
sudo system-docker exec udev udevadm trigger --action=add /dev/sdb1
```

There are several parts to this:

## Dynamically taking action on hardware addition/removal

`udev` is a common tool for this job. [`udev(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/udev) has information on its configuration.

In the example above:

```
ATTRS{ID_FS_UUID}!="161E-5755", GOTO="media_Storage_usb_drive_exit"
ACTION=="add", \
  RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/udev-mount.sh -o nodev,noexec,nosuid,uid=1100,gid=5000,umask=007 $root/$name /media/Storage"
ACTION=="remove", \
  RUN{program}+="/usr/bin/udev-umount.sh /media/Storage"
LABEL="media_Storage_usb_drive_exit"
```

In other examples online you may see `KERNEL` used, but this can be fragile as the specific name associated with an external device is not static. Here we use `ID_FS_UUID`. This and the other attributes associated with your device can be found by executing `udevadm info /dev/sdb1` (as an example). It's important to use something that won't be overwritten or may be used by another hard drive. Other important information from this command includes `DEVPATH` and `DEVNAME`.

## Configuring `udev` in RancherOS.

The configuration above would usually be placed into `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, but we need to put it in the correct `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.

In RancherOS the `udev` daemon (`udevd`) runs as a container, visible by executing:

```sh
sudo ros service ps
```

or

```sh
sudo system-docker ps
```

RancherOS system containers can be configured using [`cloud-config`](http://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.1/en/configuration/#cloud-config). We can write files into system containers using the [`write_files`](http://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/configuration/write-files/) directive as demonstrated above.

## Making mounts available to the `console` and other spawned docker containers.

By default the `udev` container doesn't share [media volumes](https://github.com/rancher/os/blob/947049cc3c9e47cb1fe907b4b8221817057e9bb4/os-config.tpl.yml#L191) so we run the provided scripts which execute mount inside the `console` system container. It has the properties we need:

- `mount` and `umount` available (unlike the `docker` container)
- `media-volumes` mounted

## Notes

1. Be careful with paths in `RUN` commands, as non-absolute paths will be resolved relative to `/usr/lib/udev/`.
2. You can view attributes of your device by executing `udevadm info <device path>` e.g. `udevadm info /dev/sdb1`.
3. You can test your `udev` configuration in the `console` container (the default container that spawns when you ssh into RancherOS) you can place the file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and test using e.g. `udevadm test --action=add <DEVPATH>`
4. The logs for `udevd` are accessible via `dmesg` (per [`rancher/os#2253`](https://github.com/rancher/os/issues/2253)). `udevadm --log-priority=debug` sets the log level dynamically